# Mercurial - abort: could not lock repository

Tags: mercurial, repository

It is my first time using Mercurial and I am having trouble with it.

I used hg add * and now I am trying to commit by using the hg com command but It's giving me back this error:

```
Nathans-MacBook-Pro:biogene Nathan$ hg com -m "First time commit"
abort: could not lock repository /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/merc/biogene: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone provide any insight as to what's going on? That directory certainly exists as I am currently inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a repository here first?

```
hg init
```